# Проблема с хоткеями в IDEA Ultimate Edition

Tags: intellij-idea

Хоткеи стоят дефолтные, сразу после установки появилась проблема такого рода: при выделении текста Shift + Стрелки не происходит выделения, а происходит эффект Ctrl + Стрелки. При старте же всегда курсор установлен, как будто Insert "включен". Через бекспейс выделенный текст не удаляется, а просто убирается выделение, Ctrl-C/V не работают или работают, но не всегда. И подобного рода проблемы, кто сталкивался?

Comment: операционная система?

Comment: ОС - Windows 8.1

Answer (score 3):

Была такая же проблема в IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3 в Tools убрал галку с Vim Emulator (Ctrl+Alt+V).После этого все заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте Alt+Ctrl+S или File ->Settings. Там IDE Settings ->keymaps. Убедитесь, что Keymaps на самом деле выставлен в default. Если да, посмотрите настройки горячих клавиш. Например, что Ctrl + C правда там есть. Если все верно, ищите сторонние приложения, которые могут перехватывать горячие клавиши(Например punto swhtcher или еще что-то)

Comment: Стоит default, Ctrl-C имеется, подобное ПО не использую.
Просто после первой установки появилась такая проблема, найти решение так и не могу, переустановка тоже не помогала

Comment: Наблюдается ли проблема в других программах? А если запущена IDEA ?

Comment: Нет, не наблюдается, как с IDEA, так и без нее

Comment: Попробуйте создать новый профиль горячих клавиш и там настроить все заново

Comment: Еще не попробовал, но могу сказать, что эта проблема только в 14 версии IDEA, поставил 13 UE, и она работает как надо (кстати, IDEA 14 CE работает тоже как надо, то же самое и с AndroidStudio - работает без подобных "артефактов").

Comment: Я просто решил удалить папку с конфигами от 14 IDEA UE и запустить с новыми. Итог: все заработало, как надо. Я не знаю, что это было, возможно, просто криво поставилось первый раз, но вот такая ситуация.

Answer (score 1):

Отключить в программе **плагин  IdeaVim**.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 1):

Очень помогли предыдущие ответы, действительно плагин Idea Vin мешает, и не дает работать большинству стандартных сочетаний клавишь, видимо он их перенастраивает и из за этого они не работают.

Answer (score 0):

Отключить в программе плагин  intelvim.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?